# VSCode timeline filled up by local history when I keep auto save open

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My VSCode timeline used to be a clean and tidy status, I can know what code I changed by compare the uncommited code and previeous commited code. But at some time I update VScode, timeline became confusing, every save/undo/redo will be recorded. Each timeline has only 1 or 2 lines' code changed, and i can barely find what I want to know.
[image]

I tried to turn "Workbench › Local History" disabled, but I cannot find the Uncommit changes  .

So, how can I close the local history and find Uncommit changes back?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the Local History entries and just leave the git timeline by clicking on the little funnel icon to the right and deselecting `Local History`.

[image: timeline filter demo]

Comment: yes, i've tried this before, but i want "uncommitted changes" back. (sry, I didn't upload the pic, i've updated it now.